# Праздники и выходные

Tags: дата, календарь

Появилась задача учитывать официальные праздники и выходные в приложении (Российская Федерация). Вопрос, существует ли какой-нибудь сервис, откуда их можно получить (в начале каждого года например). Не хочется постоянно возвращаться к клиенту и вносить эти даты в базу.

Comment: праздники и выходные где?

Comment: @Grundy Россия, уточнил

Comment: http://calendar.yoip.ru/holiday/2017-calendar-prazdnikov.html

Comment: @Sublihim Календарей в интернете полно. Нужен именно сервис, с которого можно получить даты в конкретном формате (XML, JSON), и который не отвалится через год.

Comment: [Пример с апи](http://basicdata.ru/api/json/calend/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

То, что Вам нужно, называется "Производственный календарь". В итоговом виде он в официальной версии не существует и составляется на основании календаря года и действующего законодательства.

Получить его можно, например, с правовых сайтов (Consultant.ru, Garant.ru и пр.), порталов занятости (HH.RU, SuperJob.RU и пр.) и других.

> Нужен именно сервис, с которого можно получить даты в конкретном формате (XML, JSON), и который не отвалится через год.

[Портал открытых данных России](http://data.gov.ru/opendata/7708660670-proizvcalendar) устроит?

Альтернативный источник: [ссылка 1](http://xmlcalendar.ru/), [ссылка 2](https://github.com/xmlcalendar/data/tree/master/ru).

Comment: Да, как раз наткнулся тоже на этот портал. Устроит, что-нибудь придумаем. Жаль, что нет API, а только файлы, название которых может измениться в будущем, но видимо это максимум. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно, конечно, попробовать открыть страницу поиска по термину и распарсить результат... или понадеяться, что http://xmlcalendar.ru/, он же https://github.com/xmlcalendar/data/tree/master/ru, через год не помрёт.

Comment: Разобрался с официальным API! Получился такой Get запрос: http://data.gov.ru/api/json/dataset/7708660670-proizvcalendar/version/20151123T183036/content
Добавьте в ответ, пожалуйста. На будущее, может кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Ах да, там еще api ключ требуется

Answer (score 1):

В формате JSON устроит? Небольшой сервис - http://basicdata.ru/api/calend/

Comment: Ну наконец-то годный ресурс! Спасибо тебе, камрад!

Answer (score 1):

Есть в Питоне модуль под названием Holidays.  Работает и для России тоже.  Вот попробуйте такой код:

```
import holidays

for date in holidays.Russia(years=2021).items():
  logger.debug(date)
```

в других языках похожие библиотеки есть.. вы не уточнили в каком формате вам нужно.  У гугла есть календарь праздников для каждой страны https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.russian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com можно оттуда читать