# Не удается получить праздничные дни python

Tags: python, datetime, library

Чтобы получить праздничные дни, я пытаюсь установить библиотеку prod-cal, но при установке библиотеки через pip:

```
pip install prod-cal
```

Вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
Collecting prod-cal
  Using cached prod-cal-0.1b7.zip (7.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [8 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wdsmpdid\prod-cal_8fe5ce7cfd604ec68c93be64d66361ac\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      import prodcal
    File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wdsmpdid\prod-cal_8fe5ce7cfd604ec68c93be64d66361ac\prodcal\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from holidays import ProdCal
  ImportError: cannot import name 'ProdCal' from 'holidays' (C:\Users\Max\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holidays\__init__.py)
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

C pip все нормально.

Изначально моя цель - получать нерабочие дни (праздничные, перенесенные праздники на будни и тп).

Возможно есть другой вариант, как это сделать? Допустим, обращаться к google календарю, но как это сделать, я тоже не нашел.

Comment: модуль не обновлялся с 2016 года и там праздники только за 2016 год. Не надо его использовать. https://github.com/vovok/prod-cal/blob/master/prodcal/prodcals/ru.py

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613672/Праздники-и-выходные